# How to make an image as a responsive on right bottom corner?

Tags: javascript, css, html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I an new to the front end. I have an image that  I want to display at right bottom corner. So,

I tried the following way

```css
.rex-logo {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rezoomexlogo" >
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250" alt="rexlogo" className="rex-logo img-responsive"/>
</div>
```

So, With this I am able to get what I wanted. But This is not a responsive and as well, when I open a debugger that time it is not working properly, it goes up so How to resolve this issue?

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: Does it have to be an `<img>` or are you open to making an element with a `background-image` and using `contains`?

Comment: actually less than 500px. should work on laptop and desktop and tablet screen.

Comment: Yes I am open to make an element with a background . @zero298

Comment: Assuming the above is supposed to be HTML, the attribute name should be `class="..."`, not `className="..."`     (If it's JSX, which I suspect based on that and the the src attribute, you'll want to either retag the question or edit the code to show plain HTML.)  (You may also want to give more info than "it is not working properly", -- it's not quite clear to me what problem you're trying to solve here.)

Comment: Sorry about that. Actually, image is not responsive is the problem and yes it is jsx.

Comment: I have added a comment @DanielBeck

Comment: file is 987 * 1644.

Comment: I cant see the class properties being applied to the image in the snippet. Your css seems fine also add a z-index to your button. It would work if you are trying to achieve it using image tag

Comment: @AKASHPANDEY There is no reason to add a z-index here.  It's not working in the snippet because the element still has the JSX "className" attribute instead of the HTML "class" attribute.

Comment: I know i was not talking about the snippet I wanted him to add it when he deploys it somewhere @DanielBeck

Comment: @AKASHPANDEY There is no need to add a z-index when he deploys it somewhere either. It's irrelevant.

Comment: @DanielBeck i think he wants to use a image as a button and if thats the case I think he would require a z-index on a web page he is not just going to insert a image on the right corner of the page

Comment: `position:fixed` creates its own stacking context. Adding a z-index would just be redundant, whether it’s an image or a button or anything else.

Answer (score -1):

I think this should be work please try

```
.rex-logo {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height: 100vh;  
}
```

Comment: This *does* work, assuming that what you're trying to do is restrict the image to no larger than viewport height, and that the class is set correctly on the image (i.e. using the `class` attribute rather than `className`.)  You may also want to add `max-width: 100vw`.  @ganesh please be specific about what you're looking for, if this isn't it.

Comment: Actually, I tried  this when I use 100vh then it takes the whole height .

Comment: The `max-height` is 100vh, so if the image is larger than the viewport it will indeed take the full height.  Is that not what you want?